# Postgresql: Query to know which fraction of the values are larger/smaller

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, ranking

I would like to query my database to know which fraction/percentage of the elements of a table are larger/smaller than a given value.

For instance, let's say I have a table `shopping_list` with the following schema:

```
   id   integer
 name   text
price   double precision
```

with contents:

```
id       name  price
 1     banana      1
 2       book     20
 3    chicken      5
 4  chocolate      3
```

I am now going to buy a new item with price 4, and I would like to know where this new item will be ranked in the shopping list. In this case the element will be greater than 50% of the elements.

I know I can run two queries and `count` the number of elements, e.g.:

```
-- returns = 4
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM shopping_list;

-- returns = 2
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM shopping_list
WHERE price > 4;
```

But I would like to do it with a single query to avoid post-processing the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the aggregate function [`PERCENT_RANK`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-HYPOTHETICAL-TABLE) which does exactly what I wanted:

```
SELECT PERCENT_RANK(4) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY price)
FROM shopping_list;
-- returns 0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

if you just want them in single query use UNION

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 'total'
FROM shopping_list
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*),'greater'
FROM shopping_list
WHERE price > 4;
```

Comment: the problem I see with this solutions is that way there are still two `SELECT` queries (maybe less efficient?) and moreover I would still need to do the ratio by myself after the query.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `avg()`:

```
SELECT AVG( (price > 4)::float)
FROM shopping_list;
```

Comment: I really like this solution, however in Postgres I had problems casting `bool` to float. I edit your solution to cast it directly to `int`

Answer (score 0):

One way to get both results is as follows:

```
select count(*) as total,
    (select count(*) from shopping_list where price > 4) as greater
from shopping_list
```

It will get both results in a single row, with the names you specified. It does, however, involve a query within a query.